# Class Library for Xamarin and Core 2.2

Tags: c#, class, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a class library for an API and a Web project targeting core 2.2 framework. It uses data annotations for a variety of reasons. One of them the fact that I use EF and need the InverseProperty tag.

I now want to add a mobile xamarin app to my project and have it use the same class library so that it can use the same models.

But the referance will not work unless i change the traget to be standard rather then core.

However as soon as i do that, annotations no longer work.

I am in a strange pickle here. 
I could create a new class library for the mobile app that would simply duplicate the code. But that kind of code duplication will surely come pack to bite me back.

1. Is there any way i can make my class library target two frameworks?
2. Is there maybe a way i should have the annotations removed to a seperate class ? and inherit from the original? But that would still be writing the code twice anyway.

Any advice on how to appreoch this would be appratiated.

Answer (score 0):

You may have two libraries with different targets that have a common shared project where you will refactor the code like you want and avoid duplication. This sounds like the possible solution for your problem, maybe there are other solutions, but this one should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit your .net project file and add

`System.ComponentModel.Annotations` for .net standard

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for xamarin and .net

This is the code for your `csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netstandard2.0' ">
   <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
 </ItemGroup>
```